# USVN virtualhost broken afer migration from apache 2.2 to apache 2.4

Tags: apache, https, migration, apache2.4

I had a USVN site on https on a virtualhost. This worked fine with apache 2.2 on Ubuntu.

Since performing a system upgrade, I ended up with apache 2.4 and a none working USVN. I tried toreconfigure the host without success...

I end up with this error :

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
```

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 443

here is my configuration for the site :

usvn.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/usvn/public
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/private/localhost.pem
ServerName svn
#alias /usvn /var/www/usvn/public
#alias / /var/www/usvn/public
<Directory "/var/www/usvn/public">
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location /svn/>
    ErrorDocument 404 default
    DAV svn
    Require valid-user
    SVNParentPath /var/www/usvn/files/svn
    SVNListParentPath off
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "USVN"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/usvn/files/htpasswd
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/www/usvn/files/authz
</Location>
```

Anyone have a hint on how to make it work again ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [installation documentation](https://github.com/usvn/usvn/wiki/Installation)

For Apache 2.4 you have to use

```
<Directory "/path/to/usvn/public">
  Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  AllowOverride All
  ## For Apache HTTP 2.4
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

For some reasons, `access_compat` fails to support USVN configuration. It is required to migrate directives to 2.4 syntax.

Comment: Thank you, tried but does not change anything. Still endup on an "misconfiguration page"

Comment: You have to review all apache configurations to migrate any "access" directives (Order, Deny, Allow...), including in =.htaccess= files

Comment: Well still stuck... Probably ill hae to try a fresh installation from start and migrate back my repo.... Has someone any hint on ho to get back repositories files when server is broken ?  Thanks

Comment: Repositories are in `files/svn/` and can be re-used as-is

Comment: With a fresh install, the generated `public/.htaccess` will match your Apache 2 version